# Scilab: "first and second input arguments must be real at line 53 of function histplot"

Tags: matlab, scilab

Why does this piece of code fail in Scilab?

```
N=1000;
U=rand(N, 1);
X=(9*U - 1)^(1/3);
histplot(200, X);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the code fails because `X` is not real. This can happen if `U` is smaller than `1/9`, which means that you take the third root of a negative number.

You can find problematic values of `U` by checking for whether the values in `X` are real.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a '`.`' per element operator missing?

```
X=(9*U - 1).^(1/3);
```

**EDIT:**
As Jonas points out Scilab histplot won't accept complex values as argument. MATLAB on the other hand fails because of the missing 'per element' operator.